# Activity fecha ao chamar no OnCreate método para criar Spinner

Tags: java, android

Tenho um Spinner que se invoco o método de criação dele no OnCreate, o programa fecha abruptamente. Acho q deve ser algo nulo ou alguma variável de outro escopo, pois se chamo o método de criar o Spinner no método do botão de submeter, ele vai normal.

Outra Coisa, é que quando os caras no youtube fazem a identificação de algum componente xml por id, eles fazem isso dentro do OnCreate, mas se faço isso e chamo o meu método para capturar os valores de um Editext, por exemplo, ele fecha, para contornar, identifico ele dentro do mesmo método de captura.

Queria saber mais sobre esse método OnCreate, e se é importante identificar os elementos dentro dele ou fazer a captura dentro do OnCreate mesmo.

Meu Código:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    meuperfil=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    avaliarcard=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    info=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    montarcard=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    submit=(Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    voltar=(Button) findViewById(R.id.voltar);
    idade=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editIdade);
    addItemsOnSpinner2();
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

 public void addItemsOnSpinner2() {
    nivel=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    String[]list={"0","1","2","3","4"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;
    dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    nivel.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}

//Se chamo o método AddItemsOnSpinner2 no método submeter ele vai normal 
public void submeter(View view){
    masculino=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.masculino);
    feminino=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.feminino);
    peso=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPeso);
    altura=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtAlt);
    /*Se não identifico os elementos aq, não é possível executar os comandos
    abaixo*/
    if(masculino.isChecked() && feminino.isChecked()) Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            "Você deve selecionar somente uma opção para sexo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "seu peso eh " + peso.getText() + "sua altura eh " + altura.getText() +
                "seu esporte eh " + nivel.getSelectedItem(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Logcat:

```
12-26 23:05:10.330 1385-1385/com.clicks.lucas.clicks E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.clicks.lucas.clicks/com.clicks.lucas.clicks.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)

at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)

at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

at com.clicks.lucas.clicks.MainActivity.addItemsOnSpinner2(MainActivity.java:106)

at com.clicks.lucas.clicks.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)

at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)

at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 

at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 

 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 

 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 

 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 

 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 

                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Meu xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="126dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="103dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="100dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtAlt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editPeso"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Altura em cm"
        android:inputType="number"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="35dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editPeso"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/masculino"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Peso em kg"
        android:inputType="number"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="53dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="204dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editIdade"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edtAlt"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Idade"
        android:inputType="number"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="53dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="204dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/voltar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:onClick="voltar"
        android:text="Voltar" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/masculino"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="Masculino" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/feminino"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/masculino"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/masculino"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editPeso"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editPeso"
        android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
        android:text="Feminino" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:text="Qual o seu sexo?"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nivelexercicios"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:onClick="submeter"
        android:text="Enviar" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/sim"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/perderpeso"
        android:text="Sim" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/nao"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_below="@+id/perderpeso"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/feminino"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/feminino"
        android:text="Não" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/perderpeso"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editIdade"
        android:text="Deseja perder peso?"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ganharmusc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_below="@+id/editIdade"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/perderpeso"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/perderpeso"
        android:text="Deseja ganhar Músculos?"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nivelexercicios"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sim"
        android:text="Defina em uma escala de 0-4 a quantidade de esporte que pratica?"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nivelexercicios"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="406dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Não da nenhum erro no logcat?

Comment: Não quando compilo ele, mas da erro na AVD, programa has stopped

Comment: Da uma olhada no logcat enquanto executa o app, com certeza deve mostrar algum erro la. Se achar, edita a pergunta e posta aqui

Comment: blz vou fazer isso

Comment: Deu NullPointerException

Comment: Edita a pergunta e posta a pilha de erros completa **em forma de texto** de preferencia. Assim fica facil rastrear a origem do nullpointer.

Comment: Verifica se o id da Spinner no teu XML é o mesmo que colocas no java no metodo addItemsOnSpinner2. Se for e para tentar perceber qual é o problema coloca uns debugs no código no metodo da Spinner através do Log.d("addItemsOnSpinner2","Erro")

Comment: Eu debuguei o código e na linha que acesso

Comment: nivel.setAdapter(dataAdapter); tá causando o problema, mas não seu porque, pois no começo do método fiz a identificação do Spinner nivel

Comment: Coloque o XML desse layout.

Comment: Não sei se tem haver, mas o Spinner não tá na minha activity principal, fiquei pensando se isso tem haver

Comment: Bem redundante kk

Comment: O método OnCreate, só acessa os componentes do Activity_Main? pois, o meu Spinner tá em outro Layout

Comment: O Spinner se chama "spinner1" mas você tá pegando um com o id "spinner". Isso vai retornar null. O findViewById só vai funcionar com os elementos que estão no layout que você definiu pelo setContentView.

Comment: Não é Spinner mesmo kkk eu troquei depois pra testar

Comment: Mas esse setContentView vou testar dentro do método

Comment: Deu Certo, vcs são fodas!!!

Answer (score 0):

O Código de criação do Spinner estava correto. O erro é que ele era chamado em um método que não enxergava a layout que criei. Era só dar um setContentView que resolvia. Problema Resolvido.